# angular 8 - custom pipes working within directives?

Tags: angular

I have an image tag like this:

```html
<img [src]="image" />
```

and what's being passed in is an unsafe url (it's an ionic application) so I created a pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe',
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  public sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
  }
  transform(value: string): SafeUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
}
```

now I have updated my html to:

```html
<img [src]="image | safe" />
```

how ever this doesn't work and image is being sanitized by Angular. I need to manually do it in  the component:

```js
this.image = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
```

only then will the image not be sanitized. Can I not use pipes in my directives? Am I doing this wrong? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl`

This is my entire pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl, SafeScript, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeSafe'
})
export class SanitizeSafePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(public _sanitizer?: DomSanitizer) {}

transform(value: any, args?: any): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript |SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl  {
 if(args) {
  switch (args) {
    case 'HTML': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    case 'STYLE': return this._sanitizer
                             .bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${value})`);
    case 'SCRIPT': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
    case 'URL'     : return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
    case 'RESOURCE': return this._sanitizer
                                .bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`url(${value})`);
       default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${args}`);
    }
   } else {
     return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but when using this with an iFrame src, I had to change case 'RESOURCE' from (`url(${value})`) to (`${value}`) for it to work.